# create javascript pyramid looping for this output:

Tags: javascript, loops

i have this but it can not resolve the problem:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let line = '';
  for (let j = 1; j <= 5 - i; j++) {
    line += '    ';
  }
  for (let k = i; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++) {
    line += `${i}` + '      ';
  }
  for (let l = 2 * i - 2; l >= i; l--) {
    line += `${l}` + '      ';
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is the output I want:

```
                1
            2       2
        3       4       3
    4       5       5       4
5       6       7       6       5
```

It forms an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
linenumber = 5
for (let i = 1; i <= linenumber; i++) {
    let line = ''
    for (let space = 1; space <= linenumber-i; space++){
        line +=  '    ';
    }
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        let numberadd =  Math.abs(j-1);
        let numberadd2 =  Math.abs(i-j);
        
        if (numberadd > numberadd2){
            numberadd = numberadd2
        }
        line += i+numberadd + '       ';
        
    }
    console.log(line)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is a very simple make a pyramid with an extra sauce. For every cell, you need to its value by closest distance relative to the 'walls'.

Comment: I am a beginner. Your answer is great to learn. Thanks a lot master @Alvi15